# Why is Chrome skipping the numericality validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, validation

I have this validation:

```
validates :year, :presence => true, :numericality => { :only_integer => true }, :uniqueness => true
```

This works fine in Firefox, but in Chrome the numericality validation isn't working. If I write `23ab` is saved as `23` and doesn't show errors. Can be because of the tag input type number of HTML5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the parameters actually being received by your action (i.e. check your `development.log`) and post information as to what's actually being sent to your controller in the `params` hash.

The validation in the model happens on the server side after the browser has transmitted the form data, before it's saved/updated in the database. So, if the exact same input from two different browsers produces different validation results, then it's probably being modified by the browser before it's being received by the controller action.

To say it another way: it's not the validation that is being skipped, it's the input data that's being modified, at least most likely. Inspect what's actually making it to your `params` hash and you'll be half way home.

Comment: You're right, must be Chrome's default behavior. I write `2a` and click outside of the input and it's turned onto `2` automatically before send the form.

Comment: Also possible that Rails is auto-generating some kind of meta-data that Chrome responds to on that field (?because of your validation?) that gets fed into the view, causing it to format it before it's sent? Just a hunch, but it would be kind of cool if it did that.